# Rasa chatbot buttons not working in MS teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, chatbot, rasa

I have deployed RASA IT helpdesk chatbot on MS teams but its buttons when clicked give an error message which says, "Something went wrong. Please try again". The buttons are well defined in the domain.yml file. I am not able to find out any other solution, please help me resolve this.
Thank you

Comment: Could you please confirm whether it's a custom 3rd party teams app, developed using Teams Bot SDK? Which technology is being used here? Any reference doc would be really helpful.

Comment: Hi @Prasad-MSFT The bot is developed using the Rasa framework which is available on the link https://github.com/RasaHQ/helpdesk-assistant#rasa-x-deployment. I did the setup on ubuntu VM (on azure), then from teams got the app_id and app_password and put in  credentials.yml file in the rasa bot. This was the setup to make the bot up and running on Teams.  I am not sure what is a custom 3rd party teams app, can u please elaborate.  The bot is not developed using Teams Bot SDK.

Comment: @Srishino, am facing same situation; did you find the issue?

Comment: yes, please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution for the above issue and here is the solution:
Just where you are defining the buttons in domain.yml file for each button add an entry-

type: "postBack"

this will make the buttons work on MS Teams.

Comment: In case to build the button(s) in actions.py:
`def make_button(title, payload, _type="postBack"): return {"title": title, "payload": payload, "type": _type}`